# Running mongodb commands through cmd on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, cmd

I have installed mongodb on windows system,

I have run mongod on `command prompt`

Now in another `command prompt` I am running `mongo` command which connected to `test` database. But when I try to execute `show collections` command nothing is happening.

I want to know how to trigger `show collection`, `create collection` commands from `cmd`

[image: Mongo command prompt]

Comment: The [**MongoDB documentation**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/mongo-shell/#mongo-shell-quick-reference) has all that you need, in particular the section [**Command Helpers**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/mongo-shell/#command-helpers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show all the databases present in MongoDB, you need to issue the **[`"show dbs"`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/mongo-shell/#command-helpers)** command at the prompt:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
> show dbs
admin   0.078GB
local   0.078GB
```

Only two databases exist i.e. the system dbs `'admin'` and `'local'`

Next, issue the command `"use new-db"` to switch from the default database to the defined database `"new-db"`. At this juncture, MongoDB will not automatically create any databases or collections yet until you manually create a collection or save a document inside. So run the following commands

```
> use new-db
switched to db new-db
> show dbs
admin   0.078GB
local   0.078GB
```

`"new-db"` does not show up after the `"show dbs"` command because it does not have any collections yet, so you need to create a test collection named `"people"`, and insert a document inside. There are a couple of ways you can go about creating a collection, you can either issue the **[`db.createCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/)** command:

The following command simply creates a collection named people:

```
> db.createCollection("people")
```

Or you can just call the collection's **[`insert()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert)** or **[`save()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db.collection.save)** command, which will automatically create the collection and the `new-db` database:

```
> db.people.save({"name": "mujaffars"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5627430e0899b9f16b9bd781"), "name" : "mujaffars" }

> show dbs
admin  0.078GB
local  0.078GB
new-db  0.078GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just,

```
> use databaseName; // first you need create own db
> db.createCollection("nameCollection");  // ... own collection show
> collection; // find exists collections  
> db.nameCollection.find(); // find all documents in collection ...
```